# begin/end member variables and range-based for-loop

Tags: c++11, for-loop

The following code compiles fine as expected:

```
struct delimited_range {
   int* b; int* e;
};

int* begin(delimited_range x) { return x.b; }
int* end(delimited_range x) { return x.e; }

int main() {
   delimited_range r;
   for (int x : r);
}
```

However, if I change the member variables' names to `begin`/`end`, as in

```
struct delimited_range {
   int* begin; int* end;
};

int* begin(delimited_range x) { return x.begin; }
int* end(delimited_range x) { return x.end; }

int main() {
   delimited_range r;
   for (int x : r);
}
```

I get compilation errors in both GCC and Clang. My understanding was that, since `delimited_range` has no member *functions* `begin()` and `end()`, range-based for-loop should use non-member functions in both cases, but it seems that compilers are trying to use the member variables as functions.

With GCC 4.8.3 I get

```
fail.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
fail.cpp:10:17: error: expression cannot be used as a function
    for (int x : r);
                 ^
fail.cpp:10:17: error: expression cannot be used as a function
```

With Clang 3.4 I get

```
main.cpp:10:15: error: called object type 'int *' is not a function or function pointer
   for (int x : r);
              ^
main.cpp:10:15: note: when looking up 'begin' function for range expression of type 'delimited_range'
   for (int x : r);
              ^
1 error generated.
```

Is this a bug in the compilers or in the standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of §6.5.4/1:

> For a range-based for statement of the form
>
> ```
> for ( for-range-declaration : expression ) statement
> ```
>
> let `range-init` be equivalent to the expression surrounded by
>   parentheses `( expression )` and for a range-based for statement of
>   the form
>
> ```
> for ( for-range-declaration : braced-init-list ) statement
> ```
>
> let `range-init` be equivalent to the `braced-init-list`. In each
>   case, a range-based for statement is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>     auto && __range = range_expression ; 
>     for (auto __begin = begin_expr,
>         __end = end_expr; 
>         __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
>         range_declaration = *__begin; 
>         loop_statement 
>     } 
> }
> ```

and given that `_RangeT` is the type of the expression, the standard explains:

> if _RangeT is a class type, the unqualified-ids begin and end are looked up in the scope of class _RangeT as if by class member access lookup (3.4.5), and if either (or both) finds at least one declaration, begin- expr and end-expr are __range.begin() and __range.end(), respectively;

It's not a compiler bug. The `begin` and `end` unqualified-ids are correctly looked up and selected. Unfortunately they are not functions in your case, therefore the compiler is supposed to trigger the error.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will first look for `begin` and `end` member *functions* in the class, before trying to look for global functions.

Comment: The point is that there are no member functions, so my first expectation was that `begin` and `end` fields would be just ignored.